# THREE.JS соединение двух элементов (sweep rail, cap)

Tags: 3d, three.js, mesh

Добрый день, буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь, разбирающийся в 3D геометрии поможет решить следующую задачу.

Есть два элемента (geometry), причем один построен на основе второго c заданным оступом (негативным или позитивным).

[image: два элемента]

Собственно задача — соединить эти два элемента в один, для чего нужно построить 
их "перемычки"

[image: перемычки]

Скорее всего, первоочережная задача это "вычленить" вершины (точки), которые лежат на краях и используя эти массивы, соединить их вместе.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь подскажет алгоритм как можно найти массивы точек, расположенных на краях элементов.

Comment: а какая геометрия используется? THREE.Geometry()? THREE.BufferGeometry? в случае последнего - индексированная или нет?

Comment: изначально объект считывается из *.obj, насколько я понимаю ObjectLoader он в конце выдает THREE.Geometry()

Comment: С математической точки зрения — полигон, одна сторона которого (или более) не имеет "смежника" относится к краю.

Comment: `THREE.ObjLoader()` как раз возвращает THREE.BufferGeometry(). Как мне видится - подход верный с поиском смежных граней. Задача тут сводится к тому, чтобы понять - сверху или снизу находится крайняя грань.

Comment: В данном случае низ или верх не принципиально, потому как надо отслеживать "цепочки" и их будет две. Думал, может есть уже похожее готовое решение. 

Как-то так...

[1] Находим первый полигон со свободной стороной. 
[2] Смотрим соседей с теме же точками, если у соседа свободная
     грань, то идем далее по цепочке.

В итоге у нас должна появится одна замкнутая цепочка.

[4] Ищем новый полигон со сободной гранью, который еще не в первой цепочке и далее к [2].

Comment: C BufferGeometry это конечно быстрее будет

Comment: Ну, вот мы и пришли к решению ;)

Comment: От теории до практики может быть как до Луны.
Опликую тут или оставлю ссылку на GitHub.

Comment: Кстати, в процессе написания кода нашел небольшой лайфках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не идеальное, но вполне рабочее решение данной проблемы.
http://vkuchinov.github.io/BuildingCaps/
[image: решение]

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, в процессе написания кода нашел небольшой лайфках.
Мне достаточно было построить "крышки" на большем элементе.
Для этого всего надо лишь просчитать THREE.ConvexGeometry().

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дальше можно поиграться с Булеаном.

Comment: Использование `THREE.ConvexGeometry()` может дать неожиданный результат.

Comment: Безусловно, поэтому пишу, то что придумали выше. Convex как запасной черновой вариант. Халтурный.